# Programming via TCP/socket to a Laser

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have the task at hand to program all of the commands from a laser GUI to python so that we can use python instead of the GUI to control the laser. The problem: I don't really know where to start. I don't have any socket programming experience nor do I have knowledge of networking but I do know a bit of programming. To give you an idea of what I need to do, here is the PDF of what I have to program. [PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qllc1kdbrnawsps/Protocol%20for%20Spitlight%20Remote%20Control%20v2.12.pdf?dl=0) (p.s. if you don't have a Dropbox, you can just download the pdf)

That's the entire agenda. I have to define a class and use the commands there to make everything available in python.

My advisor started the program already but I am not sure what the code really means. I asked him where to go from here but he insists everything is covered in the pdf. The code is below.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction of what I should read/watch to understand how to code the rest. I read through some socket intros and TCP/IP intros and I understand the gist. The thing is, socket programming is a huge area and I don't know where to cut the wheat from the chaff. Note: the if statement at the end is already done, meaning there is nothing else to add (so says my supervisor). I only need to work on the class. The code is not really cemented in. If I find a/an better/easier way to work with the commands, then I could revamp the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import PySide.QtNetwork as Network
import PySide.QtCore as Core
import configparser


class Spitlight():
    """The classe spitlight provides an interface so that we can the Innolas Spitlight Laser from python parameterize and operate.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """constructor"""
        pass

    def ReadConfig(self, ConfigFile):
        """The parameters to operate the laser will come from the configurations file with the file ending *.ini"""
        self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read(ConfigFile)

        """ here the single parameters will be read and the parameters thoroughly checked. Later we will add parameter value limits so the laser will not function without being within the value limits. 

        Initial relevant options are:
            flashbulb voltage, Repetition rate, pump duration, pockels cell control (Balance, Holdoff), delays 

        Futhermore the communication information is in the IP/Port of the laser server
        return 0 """


    def Start(self):
        """
        Open socket with information from configuration

        Send parameters to the laser and confirm that everything is in order  e.g:
        send SET_OSCILLATOR_AMPLITUDE with FLHighvoltage aus Config
        """
        self.initSocket()

        self.set_oscillator_amplitude()


    def set_oscillator_amplitude(self):
        self.tcpSocket.write("SET_OSCILLATOR_AMPLITUDE={}".format(self.Config['Laser parameter']['FLHighvoltage ']))

    def set_oscillator_delay(self):
        self.tcpSocket.write("SET_OSCILLATOR_DELAY={}".format(self.Config['Laser parameter']['FLDelay']))


    def initSocket(self):
        """ Socket initialize"""
        self.tcpSocket = Network.QTcpSocket()
        self.tcpSocket.disconnected.connect(self.connectSocket)
        self.tcpSocket.readyRead.connect(self.readData)
        self.connectSocket()

        #  regularly reconnect is stabilerregelmäßiger reconnect is more stable as leaving the socket the entire time open
        self.reconnectTimer = Core.QTimer()
        self.reconnectTimer.setInterval(120000)  # 2 minutes
        self.reconnectTimer.timeout.connect(self.reconnectSocket)
        self.reconnectTimer.start()
        return 0

    @Core.Slot()
    def connectSocket(self):
        """Socket connect"""
        return self.tcpSocket.connectToHost(self.proxyAddress, self.proxyPort)
    @Core.Slot()
    def reconnectSocket(self):
        """Socket Status verify and again connect"""
        """ Available states of tcpSocket.state() are:
        QAbstractSocket.UnconnectedState    The socket is not connected.
        QAbstractSocket.HostLookupState     The socket is performing a host name lookup.
        QAbstractSocket.ConnectingState     The socket has started establishing a connection.
        QAbstractSocket.ConnectedState      A connection is established.
        QAbstractSocket.BoundState          The socket is bound to an address and port (for servers).
        QAbstractSocket.ClosingState        The socket is about to close (data may still be waiting to be written).
        QAbstractSocket.ListeningState      For internal use only.
        """
        if self.tcpSocket.state() in [ Network.QAbstractSocket.HostLookupState, Network.QAbstractSocket.ConnectingState, Network.QAbstractSocket.ListeningState ]:
            return 0
        if self.tcpSocket.state() == Network.QAbstractSocket.ConnectedState:
            return self.tcpSocket.disconnectFromHost()

    @Core.Slot()
    def readData(self):
        data = self.tcpSocket.readAll()
        if str(data).startswith("ERROR="):
            pass
        elif str(data).startswith("WARNING="):
            pass
        elif:
            pass

    def FlOn(self):
        """send FLASHLAMP ON
        verify with GET_LASER_STATE"""

        return 0

"""testing framework:
laser start, parametrierize, flashbulb on, shutter off, shutter closed, flashbulb off, every of the functions gives a 0 when they were successful and a error message when not
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SpitligthControl = Spitlight()
    SpitligthControl.ReadConfig('SpitlightConfig.ini')
    SpitligthControl.Start()
    SpitligthControl.FlOn()
    SpitligthControl.StartEmission()
    SpitligthControl.StopEmission()
    SpitligthControl.FlOff()
```

Comment: It looks like all the nitty-gritty socket connection details have been done for you. All you have to do is is fill in the blanks. There are even two example commands already done, `set_oscillator_amplitude` and `set_oscillator_delay`.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly in the definition of those two actually mean. It's tough to fill in the blanks when I'm not sure what I should type for all of the other commands. Any help here? By the way, do you know how I can connect to the laser? In the code there is no server or port.